# Adding Square Brackets to JSON-Object

Tags: javascript, json

I get this JSON from my server. But to work with this JSON i need to Add Square Brackets to the MH Object. How can i do that. I tried `.map` but i dont get it to work for me. Is there any better solution. Or is `.map`to use there. If yes can you show me a hint how to do that. Or is there a better solution?

```
{
    "PAD": [
        {
            "PADPS286": "Dampf",
            "PADPS124": "Hans",
            "PADPS60": "2018-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "1",
            "MH": {
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 2017,
                "MHDIRW215": 2018,
                "birthdate": "2018-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "PADPS286": "Snow",
            "PADPS124": "Jon",
            "PADPS60": "2077-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "",
            "MH": {
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 4,
                "MHDIRW215": 4,
                "birthdate": "2077-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need this JSON with sqare Brackets arround teh MH Object

```
{
    "PAD": [
        {
            "PADPS286": "Dampf",
            "PADPS124": "Hans",
            "PADPS60": "2018-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "1",
            "MH": [{
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 2017,
                "MHDIRW215": 2018,
                "birthdate": "2018-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }]
        },
        {
            "PADPS286": "Snow",
            "PADPS124": "Jon",
            "PADPS60": "2077-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "",
            "MH": [{
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 4,
                "MHDIRW215": 4,
                "birthdate": "2077-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: _I tried .map but i dont get it to work._ Show what you've tried.

Comment: _I need this JSON..._ This expected json is not valid

Comment: The JSON you are saying you need would be invalid. That would make it an array with key/value mappings inside it. You would also have to wrap MH in an object.

Comment: i edited the JSON now it is  valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really "adding square brackets", it's wrapping the "MH" object in an array.

Anyway, here's a `.map` statement that will do it for you (without mutating the original data, hence the `Object.assign` shenanigans):

```
data.PAD = data.PAD.map((padObj) => Object.assign({}, padObj, {MH: [padObj.MH]}));
```

Basically, for each entry in the `PAD` array, we're merging three objects there:

- a fresh empty object `{}`
- the original `padObj` entry
- a small object that only has the MH element from the original `padObj` wrapped in an array.

The output is as expected:

```
{
  "PAD": [
    {
      "PADPS286": "Dampf",
      "PADPS124": "Hans",
      "PADPS60": "2018-05-01",
      "PADPS143": "1",
      "MH": [
        {
          "MHVSS1": [{}],
          "MHDIRW214": 2017,
          "MHDIRW215": 2018,
          "birthdate": "2018-05-01",
          "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PADPS286": "Snow",
      "PADPS124": "Jon",
      "PADPS60": "2077-05-01",
      "PADPS143": "",
      "MH": [
        {
          "MHVSS1": [{}],
          "MHDIRW214": 4,
          "MHDIRW215": 4,
          "birthdate": "2077-05-01",
          "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Great answer, exactly what i need. That solutions works fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on `data.PAD` to reassign the `MH` property to an array. Since arrays and objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, this will modify you data in place:

```
data.PAD.forEach(pad => pad.MH = [pad.MH]);
```

```js
const data = {
    "PAD": [
        {
            "PADPS286": "Dampf",
            "PADPS124": "Hans",
            "PADPS60": "2018-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "1",
            "MH": {
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 2017,
                "MHDIRW215": 2018,
                "birthdate": "2018-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "PADPS286": "Snow",
            "PADPS124": "Jon",
            "PADPS60": "2077-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "",
            "MH": {
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 4,
                "MHDIRW215": 4,
                "birthdate": "2077-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
};

data.PAD.forEach(pad => pad.MH = [pad.MH]);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `forEach` loop. On every `MH` property inside the `PAD array`, set it to an `array`, and assign it back to the object

```js
var a = {
  "PAD": [{
      "PADPS286": "Dampf",
      "PADPS124": "Hans",
      "PADPS60": "2018-05-01",
      "PADPS143": "1",
      "MH": {
        "MHVSS1": [{}],
        "MHDIRW214": 2017,
        "MHDIRW215": 2018,
        "birthdate": "2018-05-01",
        "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "PADPS286": "Snow",
      "PADPS124": "Jon",
      "PADPS60": "2077-05-01",
      "PADPS143": "",
      "MH": {
        "MHVSS1": [{}],
        "MHDIRW214": 4,
        "MHDIRW215": 4,
        "birthdate": "2077-05-01",
        "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
      }
    }
  ]
};
a.PAD.forEach((e, i) => {
  a.PAD[i].MH = [e.MH]
})
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
    "PAD": [
        {
            "PADPS286": "Dampf",
            "PADPS124": "Hans",
            "PADPS60": "2018-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "1",
            "MH": {
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 2017,
                "MHDIRW215": 2018,
                "birthdate": "2018-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "PADPS286": "Snow",
            "PADPS124": "Jon",
            "PADPS60": "2077-05-01",
            "PADPS143": "",
            "MH": {
                "MHVSS1": [
                    {}
                ],
                "MHDIRW214": 4,
                "MHDIRW215": 4,
                "birthdate": "2077-05-01",
                "MHDIRW129 ": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
};
var objMod = {};
objMod.PAD = obj.PAD.map(o => { 
  var mo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
  mo["MH"] = Array(o["MH"]); 
  return mo;
});

console.log(objMod);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an array of strings (adding brackets only around the strings) then the above may work, however if you are trying to make the property an array what you need to do is cast the JSON Property as a list in the class as per:

```
public class AddressElements 
 implements Serializable
 {
  @JsonProperty("Street")
  private List<Street> Street = new ArrayList<Street>();
  @JsonProperty("HouseNumber")
  private List<HouseNumber> HouseNumber = new ArrayList <HouseNumber>();
  @JsonProperty("Locality")
  private List<Locality> Locality = new ArrayList<Locality>();
  @JsonProperty("AdministrativeDivision")
  private List<AdministrativeDivision> AdministrativeDivision = new 
  ArrayList<AdministrativeDivision>();
  @JsonProperty("PostalCode")
  private List<PostalCode> PostalCode = new ArrayList<PostalCode>();
  @JsonProperty("Country")
  private String Country;

  <getters and setters>
}
```

The resulting output (after initializing) would look like:

```
"body": {
"Login": "ssssss",
"Password": "eeeeee",
"UseTransactionPool": "test",
"JobToken": "",
"Request": {
"parameters": {
    "Mode": "Certified"
  },
"IO": {
    "Inputs": {
      "AddressElements": {
        "Street": [
          {
            "Value": "Wilder Rd."
          }
        ],
        "HouseNumber": [
          {
            "Value": "123"
          }
        ],
        "Locality": [
          {
            "Value": "Newton"
          }
        ],
        "AdministrativeDivision": [
          {
            "Value": "NY"
          }
        ],
        "PostalCode": [
          {
            "Value": "12345"
          }
        ],
        "Country": "USA"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}